# Automatic Zabbix -> Confluence, creating too many updates

Tags: python, string-comparison, confluence, zabbix

I have a python script that runs once a day, connects to our Zabbix monitoring database and pulls out all the active monitoring checks and documents them into Confluence.

My problem is that each hosts' confluence page gets updated every time the script runs, even if the monitoring hasn't changed.

A quick hack would be to get a hash of the page content and compare it with a hash of the script-generated content and only replace when the hashes don't match. Obviously the problems with this are that the script still needs to generate whole page content for comparison, and that it replaces the whole page or not at all, loosing confluence's built-in diff checker.

I'm hoping to find a more elegant solution, especially one that may allow me to update only the differences...

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the solution you are looking for, but you could have the updates generate an external html page and then use an `{html-include}` in confluence. So the confluence pages wouldn't be updated, but their displayed content would be correct.

The problem with this is that none of the confluence pages would be updated, so if you want a feed to notify people of the changes on confluence it wouldn't get the job done.